# forEach is not a function error

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I get this error when I am trying to iterate through my JSON object with a foreach.
Can someone help, please?

Here is my JS:

```
function dateTimeChecker() {
     $.ajax({
            "url": 'get-booked.php',
            "method": "get",
            "dataType": "text",
            "cache": false
        }).done(function(jBooked) {
            var jBookedDates=JSON.parse(jBooked);
            console.log(jBookedDates);
               jBookedDates.forEach(function(jB){
                    if (jB=="11/01/2016") {console.log("works");}else{console.log("doesn't");}
        })
      });
}
```

And here is the object in question :

[image]

Also, I am wondering how can i iterate over this object if someone cares to explain. :)

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] without the AJAX calls please? I am unable to repro the error.

Comment: its object not array . so maybe you can't use foreach here .

Comment: Sorry, i thought It makes sense to put the ajax as well.

Comment: `for (var key in object) {}` then inside that `forEach` should work on the array. But forEach works for array only, not object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The response that you are receiving is a JSON. You can't use an array object's method `forEach` over a plain object. You have to use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) at this context to retrieve the enumerable own properties belongs to the parsed JSON,

```
Object.keys(jBookedDates).forEach(function(jB){
 if (jB=="11/01/2016") {
    console.log("works");
 } else {
    console.log("doesn't");
 }
});
```

For your query in the comment, you can use bracket notation to access those arrays,

```
Object.keys(jBookedDates).forEach(function(jB){
  var arr = jBookedDates[jB];
  console.log(arr); //will print the array belongs to each property.
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I t works, but now I am wondering how can access these arrays which each of my objects contain. can you help?

Answer (score 4):

forEach only works on arrays, so if you want to iterate over an object you'll need to do:

```
for (var attr in obj) {
    // attr is your obj object attribute
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
        // the magic goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Using `for in` without hasOwnProperty check leads to traverse over prototype enumerable properties too.

Comment: Oh, I've forgot to put it in here, my bad. Thanks @RajaprabhuAravindasamy

Answer (score 3):

```
Object.keys(a).forEach(elem => {  console.log(a[elem]) })
```

Answer (score 3):

> how can i iterate over this object

You can't, but you can iterate over this object's **properties**. This would be done using `Object.keys()`, which returns an **array** filled with the object's properties (or keys).

```
Object.keys(jBookedDates).forEach(function(key) {
  //jBookedDates[key] will give you the value for the current property
});
```

Please keep in mind that `.forEach` is actually `Array.prototype.forEach`. This means that the function is called on an array, **not** an object.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot iterate objects using `forEach`, since it's an `Array` class method.

There are some ways to iterate an Object:

## Using Object.keys()

You use `Object.keys()` method to get your object keys then iterate over it:

```
var keys = Object.keys(jBookedDates);

keys.forEach(function(key) {
    var item = jBookedDates[key];
    // Do your logic here
    // You will have access to the `key` variable and `item` variable
}
```

## Using jQuery.each()

jQuery provides an improved `forEach` method, that works both with an jQuery collection, array or object.

```
$.each(function(key, item) {
   // Do your logic here
   // You also will have access to `key` and `item` variables
});
```

Many other Javascript frameworks/libraries provides an custom foreach method.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use for..in instead?

ex:

```
function dateTimeChecker() {
 $.ajax({
        "url": 'get-booked.php',
        "method": "get",
        "dataType": "text",
        "cache": false
    }).done(function(jBooked) {
        var jBookedDates=JSON.parse(jBooked);
        console.log(jBookedDates);
        for (key in jBookedDates) {
            if (jBookedDates.hasOwnProperty(key))
                if (jBookedDates[key] == "11/01/2016")
                {
                    console.log("works");
                } else {
                    console.log("doesn't");
                }
}
  });
```

}

It is helpful not to always default to a jQuery solution. Understanding the mechanics of vanilla javascript will often solve a lot of problems for you that libraries cannot address without unneccessary complexity or revisions outside the area where the specific logic needs to be applied.