# Abstract Variable for msg object--looking to cycle through objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, abstract, node-red

In my Node-RED function, I've been struggling to handle the msg.payload and extract a specific component of the json involved with it.

Here's the code

```
var js = msg.payload;
var output = {};
 //var Ids = js.events.sum;//.value;
 //var labels = js.externalIds.Id;
 js.forEach(function(sum){
    output.push(js.events.sum);
})

msg.payload = output;
console.log(msg.payload);
return msg;
```

I've tried store a "JSON.parse()"-d variable of the msg and msg.payload, but each time I received an 'unexpected o' error, which I've been informed means something was parsed redundantly.

I've been looking at

[forEach is not a function error with JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969974/foreach-is-not-a-function-error-with-javascript-array)

[forEach is not a function error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748056/foreach-is-not-a-function-error/40748105)

[SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380462/syntaxerror-unexpected-token-o-in-json-at-position-1/38380728)

But these haven't clarified how to handle msg objects.

The following have also been helpful for other causes but not for figuring out why my js variable cannot 'foreach':

https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/messages

https://nodered.org/docs/user-guide/writing-functions

The exact error is `TypeError: js.forEach is not a function`

Clarification appreciated.

**Edit**

I'm trying to select data from an api call that returns JSON of multiple instances of the same types data (different values). From those instances of the same types, I'm trying to select the returned values of one type.

For example,

Let's say the returned json is structured like this:

```
{
   "tupperware": [
       {
            "spoon": "salad spoon",
            "fork": "soup fork"
       },
       {
            "spoon": "soup spoon",
            "fork": "cake fork" 
       }
      ],
}
```

And I'm trying to select only the fork values. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

`{}.forEach` is not a function because, well, it's not. I think you want a `for in` loop.

Other issues:

1. Your `output` variable is an empty object, but you're trying to `push` to it. That won't work. That should be an array.
2. In your current `forEach` loop (that won't work) you are trying to push `js.events.sum`. I think you just need to push `sum` but it's unclear what you're actually after.

Here is an example of a `for in` loop.

```
const myObj = {test: 1};

for(const el in myObj) {
    console.log(myObj[el]);
}
```

Your code:

```
var js = msg.payload;
var output = []; // This should be an array if you intend `push`ing to it.
 for(const el in js) {
    output.push(js[el]); // Not exactly sure what you're trying to push here
 }

msg.payload = output;
console.log(msg.payload);
return msg;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: I appreciate your answer, I'm trying to get my head around it, but if I'm parsing JSON and only want to get one property from multiple lists instead of operating on properties, is this the way to go?

Comment: If you're trying to iterate over an object, you have to use `for ... in ...`. Otherwise, you'll need to convert your object to an array in order to iterate over it using `forEach` or any other iterable methods. Please remember to upvote/mark as answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I've found I'm trying to iterate over specific values in a **series** of objects within JSON. Your answer is excellent, but does not completely satisfy the question, which is my fault for not asking properly.

Comment: I just found out about the Object.keys() abstraction.